# Joomla menu with articles of a category

Tags: php, css, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

i'm rather new to joomla and I'm unable to do something simple, I have different articles and each one belongs to a category. I want to create a menù that lists all articles of a given category.

If i select "category List" as type of my menù it doesnt expand to list all my articles but instead it show a page with a list of articles :( I want to put this list as elements of my menu without doing it one by one.

Also this way whenever I add a new article and assign it a category it automatically add a menù entry for that category.

So for example:

```
Profile
  |-contacts
  |-activity
  |-resume
  |-porfolio
```

Now Profile is a category and whats below are articles of Profile category, I want to have a menù (main menù) where I have Home, Profile, ... and when I hover my mouse over Profile I want it to expand and show all my articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that you are rather new to Joomla, I looked for the simplest most straight forward solution I could find. *I haven't personally implemented this solution*, so I cannot attest to it working 100%...but in theory it should work.

1. Create a "Articles - Category" module to display a list of articles from one or more categories.
2. Purchase a Joomla plugin like "[DJ-MegaMenu](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/dj-megamenu)," which would allow you to publish modules inside your menu
3. Publish the "Articles - Category" modules inside a menu using the plug-in

Comment: I'll take it as answer, however I saw that also pro templates so that manually one by one.. Maybe you can list categories as menu in WordPress?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about WordPress to comment.